# Palindrome Prime, comparing reversed number

Tags: java

I'm new here and hopefully, someone may be able to guide me with my problem.

I have to find a number that is both prime and a palindrome
such as:

> 2 3 5 7 11 101 131 151 181 191 313 353 373 383 727 757 787 797 919 929

I believe my problem is in my `reverse()` method somehow because when I try to compare numbers in my `if` statement, for `option1` it displays prime numbers alongside other numbers. Trying to get the first 20 for now.

And sorry if the code is messy, have been working on this for a few hours.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromePrimeAndMirrorPrime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String menu = "  1. Display Prime Palindrome"
                + "\n  2. Display mirrored primes"
                + "\n  3. Exit Program";
        System.out.println(menu);

        int choice = in.nextInt();
        //menu((option1(20)));
        //reverse(562897498);
        //option1(20);
        option1(20);
    }


    public static boolean prime(int num) {
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= num / 2; divisor++) {
            if (num % divisor == 0) { 
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }

    public static void option1(int y){
        
            int numPerLine=10;
            int count =0;
            int num = 2;

            while(count <= y){              
                if(prime(num) && num == reverse(num)){  //main issue is here i think it doesnt compare it properly?
                    count++;
                    System.out.print(num + " ");
                
                    if(count%numPerLine==0){
                        System.out.println("");
                    }

                }
                num++;
            }
    }
    
    public static int reverse(int x){
        int y = x;
        while(y!=0){
            System.out.print(y%10 + "");
            y/=10;
        }
        //System.out.println();
        return x;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your `reverse()` method returns the value it is given.

Comment: Yea just noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your problem is with the reverse function

```
public static int reverse(int x){
    int y = x;
    while(y!=0){
        System.out.print(y%10 + "");
        y/=10;
    }
    //System.out.println();
    return x;
}
```

You are not actually reversing `x` but returning the same value.

---

You might want to create a reversed number and then return that.

```
public static int reverse(int x){
    int y = 0;//create the reveresed number here
    while(x!=0){
        y = y * 10 + x % 10;
        x/=10;
    }
    return y;
}
```

---

A small optimisation to your `isPrime` would be to check untill it's square root instead of `/2`.

```
for (int divisor = 2; divisor * divisor <= num; divisor++)
```

Comment: Mother of god.. thank you soo much. I tried returning y before but didn't do x/=10. Thanks once again

Comment: Ahh I see then I will add that. Also if you don't mind me asking, to find a mirrored prime like 13 17 37 71.... in my if statement I would just have something like if(prime(num) && prime(reverse(num)) && reverse(num) != num)

Comment: What I would do is to check if it is a palindrome or not first. Because if it is not a plaindrome checking prime is a waste of time. Also checking prime is costly. `if(palindrome(num) && prime(num) && prime(reverese(num))`

Comment: Once again thanks you were a huge help! I will be able to sleep in a few mins lol once I clean the code up a bit.